# SwiftUI chart correctly displaying the filled area beneath the graph

Tags: swiftui, charts

I'm using `SwiftUI chart` to display a graph. The task is to make the area beneath (or above) the graph shaded until the gray line, which has a value of `80`.

My shaded area is not displaying correctly. Can you provide guidance on what to do?

```
Chart {
    ForEach(Array(vm.weightMeasurs.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, measure in
        LineMark(
            x: .value("Index", index),
            y: .value("Value", measure)
        )
        .foregroundStyle(Colors.foodCircle)
        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
        PointMark(
            x: .value("Index", 3),
            y: .value("Value", vm.weightMeasurs.last!)
        )
        AreaMark(x: .value("Index", index),
                 yStart: .value("Value", measure),
                 yEnd: .value("Value", 80))
        .foregroundStyle(curGradient)
        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
    }
    RuleMark(y: .value("Limit", 80))
        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
}
.chartYScale(domain: vm.yMin...vm.yMax)
.padding()
```

[image]

I tried modifying the `AreaMark`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hey, I’m having the exact same issue. did you come up with a solution?

Comment: no, i skip this task)